# Quasi-Concavity of Function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Consider the following function:
$$f\left(x,y\right) = -x\cdot\ln\left( 0.5\right) - \left( y-x \right)\cdot\ln\left( 1-0.5e^{-x}\right) - \left( b-y \right)\cdot\ln\left( 1-0.5e^{-y}\right)$$
where $x$ and $y$ are subject to constraints $1 \leq x < y < b$. Note $b$ is a constant.

Show this function is quasiconvex over the given domain.

I've tried the level set approach but am having difficulty reasoning about the convexity of the resulting domains so am at a bit of an impasse. It seems to me that the answer must have something to do with the fact that the sum of quasiconvex functions on *different* domains is still quasiconvex.